# How to make this DataTemplateSelector work?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplateselector

In my Viewmodel I have the properties `LoggedInAs` of type string and `EditMode` of type bool. I also have a List property called `ReaderList` which I bind to an ItemsControl for display purposes like this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="ReaderList" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource drts}"/>
```

I am using Caliburn.Micro, so the Binding is done automatically by the naming. I want to use a DataTemplateSelector because if the application is in EditMode and the Person is the one that is logged in I want a fundamentally different display. So here is my declaration of the resources,

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OtherPersonTemplate"> ... </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CurrentUserIsPersonTemplate"> ...  </DataTemplate>

    <local:DisplayReaderTemplateSelector x:Key="drts" 
           IsLoggedInAs="{Binding LoggedInAs}" 
           IsEditMode="{Binding EditMode}" 
           CurrentUserTemplate="{StaticResource CurrentUserIsPersonTemplate}"
           OtherUserTemplate="{StaticResource OtherPersonTemplate}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and here the code for the class:

```
public class DisplayReaderTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector {
    public DataTemplate CurrentUserTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate OtherUserTemplate { get; set; }

    public string IsLoggedInAs {get; set;}
    public bool IsEditMode { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container){
        var _r = item as Person;
        if (IsEditMode && _r.Name == IsLoggedInAs) return CurrentUserTemplate;
        else return OtherUserTemplate;
    }
}
```

For some reason the application crashes while instantiating the Viewmodel (resp. the View). Where is the error, and/or how could I solve this problem alternatively?

EDIT: The Crash was due to the binding expressions in the construction of the DisplayReaderTemplateSelector - because `IsLoggedIn` and `EditMode` are not DependencyProperties.

So the question now is: how can I have a DataTemplateSelector that depends on the status of the ViewModel if I cannot bind to values?

Comment: Where is the code for the ViewModel?  What is the error?

Comment: The ViewModel is pretty big, the only relevant parts for this problem I described above are the two exposed properties. The error is: An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. The application runs, but crashes when I switch to the VM above (The StartUp ViewModel works fine, after I log in, where the above VM is used it crashes).

Comment: Look at the TargetInvocationException's InnerException, there's often useful information there.

Comment: @MW, I found the problem via the InnerException (had just moved to VS2012, was the first real bug since the move, took me a while to find the InnerException there - because you can't! Back to VS2010...). I edited the question accordingly. But still, my problem is not solved. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the Context attached property (think it's View.Context). You can have multiple views for the same vm, it uses context to locate an alternative view

Comment: Ill post a potential solution in a sec, just waiting for Windows updates to stop abusing my laptop

Comment: Charleh, please do! I managed to make a working, but unelegant solution by storing `IsLoggedInAs` and `EditMode` as properties in a static class, hence I can access them in the DataTemplateSelector ... Not conceptually satisfying though...

Comment: I've added a solution which I think is pretty decent using an interface and a tweak to `ViewLocator`, there may be an alternative, but this is pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you could use a `DataTemplateSelector` or something of that ilk, it probably won't surprise you to find that in Caliburn.Micro has this functionality built-in in the form of `View.Context` and the `ViewLocator`

On your VM you can create a property which provides a context string which CM will use to resolve the View - since it uses naming conventions, you just need to provide the correct namespace/name for the sub-view along with a context string for it to locate an alternative view

In your VM you can create a context property that uses the user details to determine its value:

i.e.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public string Context 
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (IsEditMode && _r.Name == IsLoggedInAs) return "Current";
            else return "Other";
        }
    }  

    // ... snip other code
}
```

The only problem I see (one that probably has a workaround) is that you want to determine the view from inside a `ViewModel` - usually you determine the context higher up and pass that to a `ContentControl` and CM uses it when locating the view for that VM

e.g.

your main VM:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public SomeSubViewModel { get; set; } // Obviously would be property changed notification and instantiation etc, I've just left it out for the example
}
```

and associated view

```
<UserControl>
    <!-- Show the default view for this view model -->
    <ContentControl x:Name="SomeSubViewModel" />
    <!-- Show an alternative view for this view model -->
    <ContentControl x:Name="SomeSubViewModel" cal:View.Context="Alternative" />
</UserControl>
```

then your VM naming structure would be:

```
- ViewModels
|
----- SomeSubViewModel.cs
    |
    - SomeSubView.xaml
    |
    - SomeSubView
    |
    ----- Alternative.xaml
```

and CM would know to look in the `SomeSubView` namespace for a control called `Alternative` based on the original VM name and the `Context` property (SomeSubViewModel minus Model plus dot plus `Context` which is SomeSubView.Alternative)

So I'd have to have a play around as this is the standard way of doing it. If you were to do it this way you'd have to either create a sub viewmodel and add a `ContentControl` to your view and bind the `View.Context` property to the `Context` property on the VM, or add the `Context` property higher up (to the parent VM).

I'll look at some alternatives - if there is no way to get the current ViewModel to decide its view based on a property using standard CM, you could customise the `ViewLocator` and maybe use an interface (IProvideContext or somesuch) which provides the `ViewLocator` with a context immediately -(I don't think you can't hook directly into the view resolution process from a VM)

I'll come back with another answer or an alternative shortly!

EDIT:

Ok this seems to be the most straightforward way to do it. I just created an interface which provides `Context` directly from a VM

```
public interface IProvideContext
{
    string Context { get; }
}
```

Then I customised the `ViewLocator` implementation (you can do this in `Bootstrapper.Configure()`) to use this if no context was already specified:

```
ViewLocator.LocateForModel = (model, displayLocation, context) =>
{
    var viewAware = model as IViewAware;

    // Added these 3 lines - the rest is from CM source
    // Try cast the model to IProvideContext
    var provideContext = model as IProvideContext;

    // Check if the cast succeeded, and if the context wasn't already set (by attached prop), if we're ok, set the context to the models context property
    if (provideContext != null && context == null)
         context = provideContext.Context;

    if (viewAware != null)
    {                    
        var view = viewAware.GetView(context) as UIElement;
        if (view != null)
        {
#if !SILVERLIGHT && !WinRT
            var windowCheck = view as Window;
            if (windowCheck == null || (!windowCheck.IsLoaded && !(new WindowInteropHelper(windowCheck).Handle == IntPtr.Zero)))
            {
                LogManager.GetLog(typeof(ViewLocator)).Info("Using cached view for {0}.", model);
                return view;
            }
#else
            LogManager.GetLog(typeof(ViewLocator)).Info("Using cached view for {0}.", model);
            return view;
#endif
        }
    }

    return ViewLocator.LocateForModelType(model.GetType(), displayLocation, context);
};
```

This should work for you and allows you to set the context directly on the target `ViewModel` - obviously this will probably only work for a View-First approach

So all you need to do is structure your views as I showed above (the correct namespaces etc) then set the `Context` property on your VM based on the value of `IsLoggedInAs` and `EditMode`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will take a couple of days until I can check this out completely, but I will def. come back to you then!

Comment: I'll post a sample project - I've pretty much got one so... :P might as well

Comment: Ok if you want a sample I'll mail you it because the internet security server here won't let me do diddly squat :)

Comment: I managed in the end to build a solution inspired by your answer, in which I have a basic and several alternative ViewModels in my current ViewModel, bind the basic one to a `ContentControl` and set the basic one to be the right alternative one via subscibing/publishing events via an eventaggregator. Works fine, except for a bit of XAML code duplication (which I don't think your code would have circumvented). Cheers!

Comment: Still it would be nice to be able to use the `DataTemplateSelector` directly, since that's what it's made for. Too bad you can't bind values to pass in as parameters... Maybe you could bind to a property that returns a `DataTemplateSelector`, and in the getter always create a new one when the property changes, passing in the parameters in the constructor...